# Kepler Jjupin Script

Tags: scripting, jira, jira-plugin

I wanted to add a sill script to a post function of my workflow for making automatic assignee depends on conditions. Script doesn't have any syntax error but I cannot create any issue. I got this error on screen : "Error creating issue:Exception while executing SIL program <>

Sil script:

```
if (reporter=="abc.abc" ) {
assignee ="ddd.ddd";
}else {
assignee = "eee.eee" ;
}
```

Error logs:

```
2015-08-14 02:20:55,030 http-bio-8181-exec-22 ERROR Elif.Guney 140x7021x1 rfyl2i 192.168.1.1 /secure/QuickCreateIssue.jspa [jira.commons.silrunner.UnifiedSilRunner] Exception while executing SIL program >>assignee<<
com.keplerrominfo.jira.commons.jira.utils.JiraOperationException: Update failed for issue >>null<<, error was java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source GenericValue can not be null.
                at com.keplerrominfo.jira.commons.jira.utils.IssueUtils.updateIssue(IssueUtils.java:437)
                at com.keplerrominfo.jira.commons.ivm.SILIssue.saveFieldsToIssue(SILIssue.java:125)
                at com.keplerrominfo.jira.commons.ivm.DefaultIssueVariableResolver.applyResults(DefaultIssueVariableResolver.java:51)
                at com.keplerrominfo.jira.commons.ivm.IssueSILInterpreter.interpret(IssueSILInterpreter.java:155)
                at com.keplerrominfo.jira.commons.silrunner.UnifiedSilRunner.interpret(UnifiedSilRunner.java:119)
                at com.keplerrominfo.jira.commons.silrunner.UnifiedSilRunner.interpret(UnifiedSilRunner.java:93)
                at com.keplerrominfo.jira.commons.silrunner.UnifiedSilRunner.interpret(UnifiedSilRunner.java:67)
                at com.keplerrominfo.jira.plugins.jjupin.sil.SilPostFunction.execute(SilPostFunction.java:44)
                at com.opensymphony.workflow.AbstractWorkflow.executeFunction(AbstractWorkflow.java:1050)
                at com.opensymphony.workflow.AbstractWorkflow.transitionWorkflow(AbstractWorkflow.java:1446)
                at com.opensymphony.workflow.AbstractWorkflow.initialize(AbstractWorkflow.java:615)
                at com.atlassian.jira.workflow.OSWorkflowManager.createIssue(OSWorkflowManager.java:879)
                at com.atlassian.jira.issue.managers.DefaultIssueManager.createIssue(DefaultIssueManager.java:711)
                at com.atlassian.jira.issue.managers.DefaultIssueManager.createIssue(DefaultIssueManager.java:622)
                at com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.DefaultIssueService.create(DefaultIssueService.java:197)
                at com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.DefaultIssueService.create(DefaultIssueService.java:162)  <+3>
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.hostcomponents.impl.DefaultComponentRegistrar$ContextClassLoaderSettingInvocationHandler.invoke(DefaultComponentRegistrar.java:129)
                at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy380.create(Unknown Source)  <+3>
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.bridge.external.HostComponentFactoryBean$DynamicServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(HostComponentFactoryBean.java:154)
                at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy380.create(Unknown Source)
                at com.atlassian.jira.quickedit.action.QuickCreateIssue.doExecute(QuickCreateIssue.java:277)  <+1> (ActionSupport.java:165)
                at com.atlassian.jira.action.JiraActionSupport.execute(JiraActionSupport.java:88)  <+7> (DefaultInterceptorChain.java:39) (NestedInterceptorChain.java:31) (ChainedInterceptor.java:16) (DefaultInterceptorChain.java:35) (GenericDispatcher.java:225) (GenericDispatcher.java:154) (JiraWebworkActionDispatcher.java:152)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)  <+2> (ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)  <+14> (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (ChainedFilterStepRunner.java:87) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (XContentTypeOptionsNoSniffFilter.java:22) (AbstractHttpFilter.java:31) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (HeaderSanitisingFilter.java:44) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (IteratingFilterChain.java:46) (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
                at com.idalko.jira.plugins.igrid.WebResourceIncludeFilter.doFilter(WebResourceIncludeFilter.java:160)  <+3> (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78) (IteratingFilterChain.java:42) (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
                at com.atlassian.jira.tzdetect.IncludeResourcesFilter.doFilter(IncludeResourcesFilter.java:39)  <+3> (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78) (IteratingFilterChain.java:42) (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
                at com.atlassian.jira.baseurl.IncludeResourcesFilter.doFilter(IncludeResourcesFilter.java:38)  <+8> (AbstractHttpFilter.java:31) (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78) (IteratingFilterChain.java:42) (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70) (ContextFilter.java:25) (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78) (IteratingFilterChain.java:42) (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
                at com.atlassian.greenhopper.jira.filters.ClassicBoardRouter.doFilter(ClassicBoardRouter.java:59)  <+3> (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78) (IteratingFilterChain.java:42) (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
                at com.atlassian.mywork.client.filter.ServingRequestsFilter.doFilter(ServingRequestsFilter.java:37)  <+3> (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78) (IteratingFilterChain.java:42) (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
                at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFixupFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFixupFilter.java:36)  <+3> (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78) (IteratingFilterChain.java:42) (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
                at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsDispatcherFilter.java:60)  <+3> (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78) (IteratingFilterChain.java:42) (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
                at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFilter.java:92)  <+3> (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78) (IteratingFilterChain.java:42) (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
                at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsMatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsMatcherFilter.java:56)  <+3> (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78) (IteratingFilterChain.java:42) (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
                at com.atlassian.labs.botkiller.BotKillerFilter.doFilter(BotKillerFilter.java:36)  <+23> (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78) (IteratingFilterChain.java:42) (ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77) (ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (AccessLogFilter.java:103) (AccessLogFilter.java:87) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (XsrfTokenAdditionRequestFilter.java:54) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (SiteMeshFilter.java:181) (SiteMeshFilter.java:85) (SitemeshPageFilter.java:124) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (ChainedFilterStepRunner.java:87) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (IteratingFilterChain.java:46) (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
                at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:61)  <+3> (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78) (IteratingFilterChain.java:42) (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
                at com.quisapps.jira.fieldsecurity.filter.FieldSecurityFilter.doFilterChainWithProfiling(FieldSecurityFilter.java:212)
                at com.quisapps.jira.fieldsecurity.filter.FieldSecurityFilter.doFilterInterval(FieldSecurityFilter.java:152)
                at com.quisapps.jira.fieldsecurity.filter.FieldSecurityFilter.doFilter(FieldSecurityFilter.java:58)  <+22> (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78) (IteratingFilterChain.java:42) (ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77) (ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (SecurityFilter.java:239) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (TrustedApplicationsFilter.java:100) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (BaseLoginFilter.java:172) (JiraLoginFilter.java:70) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (IteratingFilterChain.java:46) (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70) (OAuthFilter.java:79) (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78) (IteratingFilterChain.java:42) (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
                at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:61)  <+13> (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78) (IteratingFilterChain.java:42) (ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77) (ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (ProfilingFilter.java:99) (JIRAProfilingFilter.java:19) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (AbstractJohnsonFilter.java:71) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
                at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
                at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)  <+10> (UrlRewriteFilter.java:394) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (GzipFilter.java:82) (GzipFilter.java:59) (JiraGzipFilter.java:55) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (IteratingFilterChain.java:46) (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
                at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.JiraAnalyticsFilter.doFilter(JiraAnalyticsFilter.java:40)
                at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)  <+3> (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78) (IteratingFilterChain.java:42) (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
                at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:61)  <+40> (DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78) (IteratingFilterChain.java:42) (ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77) (ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (ChainedFilterStepRunner.java:87) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (AbstractCachingFilter.java:33) (AbstractHttpFilter.java:31) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (AbstractEncodingFilter.java:41) (AbstractHttpFilter.java:31) (PathMatchingEncodingFilter.java:49) (AbstractHttpFilter.java:31) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (JiraStartupChecklistFilter.java:79) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (MultipartBoundaryCheckFilter.java:41) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (ChainedFilterStepRunner.java:87) (JiraFirstFilter.java:60) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) (ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) (StandardWrapperValve.java:220) (StandardContextValve.java:122) (AuthenticatorBase.java:501) (StandardHostValve.java:171) (ErrorReportValve.java:103) (StandardEngineValve.java:116) (AccessLogValve.java:950) (CoyoteAdapter.java:408) (AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070) (AbstractProtocol.java:611) (JIoEndpoint.java:316)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source GenericValue can not be null.
                at com.atlassian.jira.association.NodeAssociationStoreImpl.getSinksFromSource(NodeAssociationStoreImpl.java:33)
                at com.atlassian.jira.issue.managers.DefaultIssueManager.getEntitiesByIssue(DefaultIssueManager.java:478)
                at com.atlassian.jira.util.JiraEntityUtils.updateDependentEntities(JiraEntityUtils.java:164)
                at com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.AbstractVersionsSystemField.updateIssueValue(AbstractVersionsSystemField.java:535)
                at com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.AbstractVersionsSystemField.updateValue(AbstractVersionsSystemField.java:415)
                at com.atlassian.jira.issue.managers.DefaultIssueManager.updateIssue(DefaultIssueManager.java:841)
                at com.atlassian.jira.issue.managers.DefaultIssueManager.updateIssue(DefaultIssueManager.java:825)
                at com.keplerrominfo.jira.commons.jira.utils.IssueUt
```

Comment: We cannot see your image. Please post a link and somebody will edit it in your image.

Comment: hi , i edited my question and wrte the error on screen that i got. so there is no need for image

Comment: thank you for making the edit. Looking over your question, would you please choose a more descriptive title. As written, your title is too broad because it is only your tag words.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your script assumes it is running in the context of an issue (by using variables like `assignee` and `reporter`).

The log, sort of, says that here: "Update failed for issue >>null<<"

A common scenario where you think you're in the context of an issue (but are not) is on the Create Screen. In this scenario, the Issue hasn't been created yet, so you'll need to rely on Live Fields to manage this scenario.